# ScyllaDB version same after upgrade

Tags: centos, scylla

I have followed the docs https://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-opensource/upgrade-guide-from-2.2-to-2.3/upgrade-guide-from-2.2-to-2.3-rpm/#upgrade-procedure  and my version has remained the same. It has not upgraded to 2.3.  Is there anything I can do or check?

I have followed the following https://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-opensource/upgrade-guide-from-2.2-to-2.3/upgrade-guide-from-2.2-to-2.3-rpm/

But I am still on version 2.2

```
[centos@ip-192-168-4-204 ~]$ sudo systemctl stop scylla-server
[centos@ip-192-168-4-204 ~]$ scylla --version
2.2.1-0.20181021.7f24b5319
[centos@ip-192-168-4-204 ~]$  sudo yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * elrepo: reflector.westga.edu
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * updates: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
Package epel-release-7-11.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[centos@ip-192-168-4-204 ~]$ sudo yum update scylla\* -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * elrepo: reflector.westga.edu
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * updates: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
No packages marked for update
[centos@ip-192-168-4-204 ~]$ sudo systemctl start  scylla-server
[centos@ip-192-168-4-204 ~]$ scylla --version
2.2.1-0.20181021.7f24b5319
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the wrong repository. Double check it with:

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/scylla.repo
```

There is a good chance you missed step 1 here:

https://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-opensource/upgrade-guide-from-2.2-to-2.3/upgrade-guide-from-2.2-to-2.3-rpm/#download-and-install-the-new-release

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you made a mistake updating the repository file, Terri again and watch carefully for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put version details here cat /etc/yum.repos.d/scylla.repo. It will take the correct version while upgrading.